# Why some devices don't support ARCore?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arkit, vuforia, arcore

I've seen that **ARCore** has a few compatible devices (Samsung or Google Pixel), which also appear, along with a few more Android and Apple devices, in the compatible devices of *ground plane detection* in **Vuforia SDK**.

Why only those devices can support this technology and others not?

Comment: why you ask **us** the reason why **they** don't support it? We didn't develop the `ARCore`, we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CPU power problem? Possible

Marketing? Probably

Both? Surely

All ARCore-compatible devices are also compatible with Daydreams (or Tango) and ARM processor. These are certainly powerful devices but other smartphones that have nothing to envy in terms of power are not compatible. I think that power plays, but not only for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

*`What does it mean for a device to be supported to use ARCore?`*

**It means a device has passed Google's certification process for using ARCore**.

Here's what Google writes about it:

> Certification is important because we want users to have a good experience with your AR application. This is primarily related to sensitive motion tracking, which is done by combining the `camera image` and the `motion sensor input` to determine how the user's device moves through the real world.
>
> To certify each device, we check the quality of the camera, motion sensors, and the design architecture to ensure it performs as expected. Also, the device needs to have a powerful enough CPU that integrates with the hardware design to ensure good performance and effective real-time calculations.
>
> The strength of Android is in the large diversity of devices available across the world. We are constantly working with manufacturers to make sure their hardware and designs meet these requirements. At the same time, we are working internally to make sure ARCore integrates well with every model we certify to provide good experiences for users.

And look at the full list of Google [Supported Devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is just in preview "like beta" so they dont have support for all models yet.

"Note: [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/) is being offered as an developer preview so that you can start experimenting with building new AR experiences. It's also an opportunity for you to give feedback on an early version of the API. This preview is the first step in a journey to enabling AR capabilities across the Android ecosystem."
"ARCore is designed to work on a wide variety of qualified Android phones running N and later. During the developer preview, ARCore supports the following devices:"

It would be safe to assume that even when ARCore in full production it would still not work on old model because of hardware limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a question of how powerful the device's cpu is.

Computer vision requires many calculations.

In my opinion, the reason Vuforia can support more devices is because their solution is simpler and less precise than ARcore.